# Доступны ли данные matview при обновлении

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Будет ли доступно материализованное представление в процессе его обновления процедурой dbms_mview.refresh()? Какая ошибка будет выведена при обращении к нему в момент обновления? Или будут доступны старые данные? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не попробовать и не воссоздать этот кейс?

Comment: Нет возможности проверить пока, поэтому и вынужден спросить.

Comment: К тому же мне интересны сведения относительно работы этого механизма. Может узнаю что-то новое из предложенных ответов и пояснений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то когда использован `atomic_refresh => TRUE`, то это удаление строк + вставка, т.е. работают обычные правила согласованности по чтению. Если не использован, то это `TRUNCATE` и вставка. Но есть какие-то волшебные out-of-place обновления, которые стали доступны в версии 12.1.

> In out-of-place refresh, the entire or affected portions of a
>   materialized view are computed into one or more outside tables. <...> This refresh process is completed by either
>   switching between the materialized view and the outside table or
>   partition exchange between the affected partitions and the outside
>   tables.